# getJSON valid data in done callback doesn't make it to view

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

This snippet is using AngularJS, jQuery and ASP.NET to move data from server to client. So before I added the $.getJSON, I just had the single line of code $scope.cards = //array

When I added the jSON call the hard-coded $scope doesn't make it to view. I didn't see any errors in the client console either. Any ideas?

```
var cardsListController = function ($scope) {

    var uri = 'api/products';

    $.getJSON(uri)
    .done(function (data) {
        // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
        $scope.cards = [{ Id: 1 }, { Id: 2 }];  //**** this works if i move outside this method
    });
```

};

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="cardsController.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="cardsListController">
    <div id="cardsListController">
        <div ng-repeat="card in cards">
            Card {{card.Id}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You would need to use `$scope.$apply()` in the done method, since you are updating the scope from jquery ajax because angular has no idea about stuffs happening outside if it has to run its digest cycle. _But ideally you should just be using angular provided ajax services, $http or $resource so you don't have to do this  and is a better practice_

Comment: You can use $http get method to retrieve data from server, Have you tried?

Comment: Can you give me your server code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use angular [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) like [.get()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) for ajax or use [$scope.$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) to inform angularjs to run its watches

```
var cardsListController = function ($scope, $https) {

    var uri = 'api/products';

    //using angularjs
    $https.get(uri, {
        responseType: 'json'
    }).success(function () {
        $scope.cards = [{
            Id: 1
        }, {
            Id: 2
        }];
    });

    $.getJSON(uri)
        .done(function (data) {
        // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
        $scope.cards = [{
            Id: 1
        }, {
            Id: 2
        }]; //**** this works if i move outside this method

        //inform angular js to apply its watches so that the view will get updated
        $scope.$apply();
    });
};
```